# Hangfire ASP.NET Core packages

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, hangfire

I have installed the packages:

`Hangfire.AspNetCore`
`Hangfire.MemoryStorage.Core`

Here is my code:

```
using Hangfire;
using Hangfire.MemoryStorage;

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddHangfire(c => c.UseStorage(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.UseMemoryStorage()));
    services.AddMvc();
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseHangfireServer(); 
}

...

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(() => Console.Write("Easy!"), Cron.Minutely);
}
```

However, I am getting the error:

`JobStorage.Current property value has not been initialized. You must set it before using Hangfire Client or Server API.`

My application is running on `ASP.NET Core`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there an in memory job storage package for Hangfire?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43206740/is-there-an-in-memory-job-storage-package-for-hangfire)

Comment: No, because I am encountering issues even with those proposed solutions.

Comment: `RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate` looks like a static method. you aren't initializing the asp.net core pipeline

Comment: Try to move `RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(() => Console.Write("Easy!"), Cron.Minutely);` to `app.UseHangfireServer(); ` later.

Answer (score 3):

The `Main` method run before `Configure` and `ConfigureServices` so you are trying to use `Hangfire` before it's configuration happen.